# Do non-human animals have all five koshas?

Tags: philosophy, vedanta, animals, body

Do non-human animals have all of the five koshas? What about plants?

Comment: every jiva has it. the only difference between the species is the amount of jnana/karma they have

Comment: @mar What if two species have equal karma?

Comment: eh ? by definition they had different karma otherwise they wouldn't be different species. an atma born as a dog obviously did some sins and is in tamo guna predominantly compared to an atma born as a human.

Comment: @mar I can't think any reason why a fruit fly would have a different level of karma then a house fly, even though they are different species.

Comment: you really can't think of a reason ? each atma's karma determines its next birth, it's body, height, weight, parents, wealth, knowledge etc. obviously these are different between any two persons, let alone different species